# open_basedir restriction in effect File is not within the allowed path

Tags: php, apache, joomla

```
Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/futbol/data:.:/tmp:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/local/bin) in /home/futbol/data/www/futbol.kg/libraries/joomla/filesystem/folder.php on line 451
```

I get this Warning in joomla, after I log in, i really don't have idea on how to fix this, maybe there is need to change some server settings, but which one?, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your `configuration.php` file. Ensure that the log and tmp entries look like

```
public $log_path = '/home/futbol/data/www/futbol.kg/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/home/futbol/data/www/futbol.kg/tmp';
```

If these entries are correct, and you still get that message, disable all non-core system plugins, as it then must be one of them causing the problem.

Comment: @NoobKraker What helped? Disabling some plugins or fixing the paths?

Answer (score 3):

> open_basedir restriction in effect

This means that you've set the `open_basedir` setting in your php.ini; and joomla is trying to read something that's not in the configured basedir.

Remove `open_basedir` from your php.ini. This gives a false sense of security (it can easily be bypassed), and causes more troubles than it solves.

Comment: unfortunaly, i can't disable it, i don't have permission to do that :(

Comment: @NoobKraker, in these situations just try to contact the person who may have these permissions (that may be your  hosting environment)

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert ini_set('open_basedir', YOUR_BASE_DIR); into the file index.php (root of Joomla). If php settings let you override configuration, it should work.